# Erro ao inserir dados com Angular usando $http.post().then

Tags: php, javascript, html, angularjs

Não consigo inserir os dados no mysql usando o angularjs. Os dados não são enviado ao arquivo insert.php. Acredito que esteja ocorrendo um erro $http.post que eu desconheça!

Alguma sugestão ?

Sistema: http://crudangularjsphp.azurewebsites.net/index.html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo Script**

```
//Metodo adicionar
            $scope.add = function(){

                //listar
                $scope.listProducts.push({
                    id:$scope.id,
                    name:$scope.name,
                    price:$scope.price,
                    quantity:$scope.quantity
                });

                /*inserir dados no banco*/
                $http.post("insert.php", {
                    name:$scope.name,
                    price:$scope.price,
                    quantity:$scope.quantity})                  
                    .then(function(data,status,headers,config){
                        console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
                });

                //limpar os inputs
                $scope.id       = '';
                $scope.name     = '';
                $scope.price    = '';
                $scope.quantity = '';
            };
```

**Codigo PHP**

```
<?php   

    $HOST  = "xxxxxxx";
    $LOGIN = "xxxx";
    $SENHA = "xxxxxx";
    $db = "localdb";

    mysql_connect($HOST, $LOGIN, $SENHA) or die("Não foi possível a conexão com o servidor");
    mysql_select_db($db) or die("Não foi possível SELECIONAR o banco de dados");

    $data       = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $name       = mysql_real_escape_string($data->name);
    $price      = mysql_real_escape_string($data->price);
    $quantity   = mysql_real_escape_string($data->quantity);



    $sql = "INSERT INTO tprodutos('name', 'price', 'quantity') VALUES('".$name."','".$price."','".$quantity."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);


    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Teste é aqui deu certo, a unica coisa que está faltando é você retorna o ID do objeto que foi criado no servidor PHP;
Outra coisá só ta um push na lista(listProducts) depois do sucesso linha 90

Comment: Você precisa, no mínimo, dizer o porquê de não conseguir.

Comment: O id é autocriment no mysql. não passei porque ele é criado automaticamente

Comment: Mesmo ele sendo criado automático o mysql consegue retornar o id, na real e bom retorna o Obejto inteiro, assim a tela vai representar o valor correto do banco, sem dar espaço para pegadinhas do malandro, rs

Comment: Mas estou inserindo o dado no banco!

Comment: Mesmo fazendo as correções o erro persiste!

Comment: Mais alguma sugestão ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erro na sintaxe do SQL = $sql = "INSERT INTO `tprodutos` (`id`, `name`, `price`, `quantity`) VALUES (NULL, '".$name."', '".$price."', '".$quantity."');";